# Integer (or whole) numbers in arbitrary fields.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

Given an arbitrary field $K$, may I define an integer in $K$? I have found how to define an algebraic number in $K$ and how to define an integer algebraic number in $K$.

For instance, let $K=\Bbb{Z}_p$, for $p$ prime (i.e., the quotient of the ring of integers by the principal ideal generated by the prime $p$). Are there integers in $K$?

In $\Bbb{Q}$ (the field of rational numbers), the ring (Euclidean domain) of integers is generated by 1. This procedure in $K$ generates the field $K$.

I do not know even if this question is legitimate.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite easy to define an integer in any ring or field:

1. $0$, the additive identity, and $1$, the multiplicative identity, are integers.
2. Any sum of integers is an integer.
3. The additive inverse of any integer is an integer.

Let's apply this to $K=\Bbb{Z}_p$. All of the elements in $K$ are integers, because all of them can be expressed as $1+1+1+...+1$ for a finite number of $1$s. For example, $2$ can be expressed as $1+1$ and $4$ can be expressed as $1+1+1+1$. Since $1$ is an integer and sums of integers are integers, then all of these elements are integers. Therefore, all $k \in K$ are integers.

Thus, it is not hard to define an integer for some arbitrary ring or field: Any integer is either $0$, $1+1+1+1+...+1$ for a finite number of $1$s, or $-(1+1+1+1+...+1)$ for a finite number of $1$s.